# making div behave like iframe

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, html

I want to load content of my page inside a div element using this function:

```
function loadmypage(DIV, pageURL)
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById(DIV).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET", pageURL ,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

However when I click on a link inside the 'frame' itself, the function doesn't work. I guess the reason for that that the target element is in different page from the loaded page
itself.

So my question is: *Is there any way to make div element behave like an iframe in loading the whole page inside the frame itself?*

PS: I am not allowed to use iFrame for security reasons neither jQuery for efficiency reasons. 
links in the main page load the target normally, the problem appears when i click at any link inside these pages.

```
 <div id="nav" class="mmenu">
                                <ul type="none">

                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('viewMessages.php')">Messages</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('userHomepage.php')">My Conferences</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('availableConferences.php')">Conferences</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('incomingRequests.php')">Requests</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= #>News</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= #>Options</a></li>


                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </fieldset>

                                        <div id="collabsoft" class="collabsoft">
```

Comment: Both reasons in the PS are simply nonsense.

Comment: Once you put the responseText inside your div it is the same page.

Comment: show your links that you're clicking as well as the function you're using to setup the click event

Comment: @J.Bruni when i click on a link inisde the div itelf.

Comment: @bažmegakapa they aren't necessarily his reasons; sometimes organizations can have fairly arbitrary and retarded rules, like disallowing use of query strings in URLs (as was the case at a previous company of mine).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your links don't work because you're missing your div argument. Notice your function:

```
function loadmypage(DIV, pageURL)
{
...
```

The first argument is DIV, and you're passing the pageURL only.

```
<li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('viewMessages.php')">Messages</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('userHomepage.php')">My Conferences</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('availableConferences.php')">Conferences</a></li>
                                            <li><a  href= "javascript:loadmypage('incomingRequests.php')">Requests</a></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

`<div>` cannot be made to behave like `<iframe>` by any setting or toggle, if you imagine something like that. After all, if you want `<iframe>`, you should use `<iframe>`.

Anyway, the links that don't work probably use relative addressing. That is a reasonable expectation for the internal links on a page. For them to work from your page, you'll have to use absolute addresses.

So if you loaded the page

```
www.example.com/somedirectory/index.php
```

and it used

```
<link href="style.css" >
```

You have to use

```
<link href="www.example.com/somedirectory/style.css" >
```

etc.

So you can traverse the DOM tree, looking for `link`, `a`, `img` and all the other elements using an address in some attribute, checking those attributes, checking if they use absolute address (could be done with a regexp, but I wan't give you one now, as there are many possibilites: `http://something...`, `www.something.com/...` or even `localhost/...`) and if not, referencing them absolutely (by prepending the whole path to the webpage and directory where the downloaded document was located).

You can traverse the DOM tree with a recursive function, starting by visiting `document.body` and for every visited node, calling the function for all its element children. Although in your case, you may take advantage of `document.getElementsByTagName` to get exactly the lists of the specific elements you need.

Finally, note that due to security reasons scripts must be included from the same host (IP and even port). Therefore, scripts from other webs won't work for you remotely referenced. You'll have to download them on your server too.

TLDR: You don't need jQuery, but use `<iframe>`.